# Python combine/group by dictionaries in a list by a value in the dict

Tags: python

I have this data :

```
[
    {'name': 'INV/2021/0913', 'invoice_date': datetime.date(2021, 3, 12), 'qty_total': 5.0}, 
    {'name': 'INV/2021/0965', 'invoice_date': datetime.date(2021, 3, 14), 'qty_total': 6.0}, 
    {'name': 'INV/2021/0966', 'invoice_date': datetime.date(2021, 3, 14), 'qty_total': 7.0}, 
    {'name': 'INV/2021/0967', 'invoice_date': datetime.date(2021, 3, 14), 'qty_total': 3.0}, 
    {'name': 'INV/2021/0992', 'invoice_date': datetime.date(2021, 3, 15), 'qty_total': 4.0}
]
```

As it can be seen the middle 3 dicts have same date.

I want to combine the dictionaries having the same invoice_date and sum up the its qty_total.
Set the name attribute to "" for the combined dictionaries.
The result should look like this:

```
[
    {'name': 'INV/2021/0913', 'invoice_date': datetime.date(2021, 3, 12), 'qty_total': 5.0}, 
    {'name': '', 'invoice_date': datetime.date(2021, 3, 14), 'qty_total': 16.0}, 
    {'name': 'INV/2021/0992', 'invoice_date': datetime.date(2021, 3, 15), 'qty_total': 4.0}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what part of it did not work for you?

Comment: don't think that the solution is very difficult, the question is time complexity. How many loops it will take to get all the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `itertools.groupby`

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import groupby

l = [
    {'name': 'INV/2021/0913', 'invoice_date': datetime(2021, 3, 12).date(), 'qty_total': 5.0}, 
    {'name': 'INV/2021/0965', 'invoice_date': datetime(2021, 3, 14).date(), 'qty_total': 6.0}, 
    {'name': 'INV/2021/0966', 'invoice_date': datetime(2021, 3, 14).date(), 'qty_total': 7.0}, 
    {'name': 'INV/2021/0967', 'invoice_date': datetime(2021, 3, 14).date(), 'qty_total': 3.0}, 
    {'name': 'INV/2021/0992', 'invoice_date': datetime(2021, 3, 15).date(), 'qty_total': 4.0}
]
res = []
for k, v in groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x["invoice_date"]), key=lambda x: (x["invoice_date"])):
    val = list(v)
    res.append(
        {"name": " " if len(val)>1 else val[0]["name"], "invoice_date": k, "qty_total": sum(vals["qty_total"] for vals in val)}
    )
print(res)
```

Output

```
[{'name': 'INV/2021/0913',
  'invoice_date': datetime.date(2021, 3, 12),
  'qty_total': 5.0},
 {'name': ' ', 'invoice_date': datetime.date(2021, 3, 14), 'qty_total': 16.0},
 {'name': 'INV/2021/0992',
  'invoice_date': datetime.date(2021, 3, 15),
  'qty_total': 4.0}]
```

Comment: Thank you much. It works as I wanted it.

Comment: @Sash Sinha Your solution worked the best in my origional progam and data. I actually had simpilfed the data for convenience.  And after trying out both of the anwers I didnt needed to write extra code for the fields which i have not shown here.

Comment: @Sash Sinha Please repost your answer. I dont see it anymore to accept it as answer

Comment: @Khaalidi If he reposts then accept his because it fits well in your program else accept mine. Its your choice.

Comment: Your answer worked too just as I wanted it . If I had a choice to accept both I would definitely do .

Comment: I understand your point.

Comment: Thank again @Deepak Tripathi , I've used and modified your answer in my program as per my need and using your approach .